# How to overwrite levels of multiple factor variables in R using for loop?

Tags: r, loops, for-loop

I have a data frame where there are multiple factor variables with the same levels. Listed the levels below

`"Completely Agree (3)" "Do not Agree (1)"     "Somewhat Agree (2)"`

There are around 18 variables that have the same three levels. I want to use for loop and overwrite these levels in the following manner

> **Do not Agree and Somewhat Agree** should be **0**

> **Completely Agree** should be **1**

I tried using the following code

```
for (i in LoopVec.St){
  levels(data[,i]) <- c(1,0,0)
}
```

LoopVec.St has the column names of all the 18 variables that has the same levels.

`levels(data[,i]) <- c(1,0,0)` worked when I used it for a single variable. But when I use it in the for loop it throws the below error.

> Error in `levels<-`(`*tmp*`, value = c(1, 0, 0)) :  factor level [3] is duplicated

Please help me out with this.

Comment: Without site of your data, it's difficult to give you concrete advice.  But a tidyverse solution using `across` would allow you to modify all 18 variables in a single line without use of a loop.  Incidentally, this is  almost certainly a case where [tidy](https://cran.r-project.org/web/packages/tidyr/vignettes/tidy-data.html)ing your data would be helpful.

Comment: @Limey - could you please elaborate a bit on this?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In response to OP's request in comments...

```
library(tidyverse)

# Test data.  3 questions just to demonstrate the principle.
d <- tibble(
       Participant=1:10,
       Q1=factor(sample(1:3, 10, TRUE), labels=c("Do not Agree (1)", "Somewhat Agree (2)","Completely Agree (3)")),
       Q2=factor(sample(1:3, 10, TRUE), labels=c("Do not Agree (1)", "Somewhat Agree (2)","Completely Agree (3)")),
       Q3=factor(sample(1:3, 10, TRUE), labels=c("Do not Agree (1)", "Somewhat Agree (2)","Completely Agree (3)"))
)
```

To recode the factors

```
# Recode untidy data
d %>% mutate(
        across(
          starts_with("Q"), 
          function(x) factor(as.numeric(x) == 3, labels=c("Do not completely agree (1&2)", "Completely agree (3)"))
        )
      )

# Tidy the data
dTidy <- d %>% 
           pivot_longer(
             cols=starts_with("Q"),
             values_to="Response",
             names_to="Question"
           )
dTidy

# Recode tidy data            
dTidy %>% 
   mutate(
     Response=factor(
                as.numeric(Response) == 3, 
                labels=c("Do not completely agree (1&2)", "Completely agree (3)")
              )
   )
```

Not much difference so far.  The benefit of tidy data becomes more apparent when we try to *do* something with it.  As a simple example, plot a histogram of the questions.  The untidy data isn't particularly amenable.  Here's a simple summary:

```
# Plot untidy data
doPlots <- function(data) {
  print(data %>% ggplot() + geom_bar(aes(x=Q1)))
  print(data %>% ggplot() + geom_bar(aes(x=Q2)))
  print(data %>% ggplot() + geom_bar(aes(x=Q3)))
}

d %>% doPlots()
```

Anything else is quite awkward.  With tidy data, it's simple:

```
# Plot tidy data
dTidy %>% 
  ggplot() +
  geom_bar(aes(x=Response)) +
  facet_grid(rows=vars(Question))

# Or
dTidy %>% 
  ggplot() +
  geom_bar(aes(x=Response, fill=Question))
```

In addition, suppose a different data set arrives, with more questions than the orginal.

```
# Now add another Question  
d <- d %>% mutate(Q4=factor(sample(1:3, 10, TRUE), labels=c("Do not Agree (1)", "Somewhat Agree (2)", "Completely Agree (3)")))

dTidy  <- dTidy %>% 
            bind_rows(
              tibble(
                Participant=1:10, 
                Question="Q4", 
                Response=factor(sample(1:3, 10, TRUE), labels=c("Do not Agree (1)", "Somewhat Agree (2)", "Completely Agree (3)"))
              )
            )
```

The doPlot function needs to be rewritten: it ignores Q4.

```
d %>% doPlot()
```

But the tidy code is robust and needs no changes

```
dTidy %>% 
  ggplot() +
  geom_bar(aes(x=Response)) +
  facet_grid(rows=vars(Question))
```

Using tidy data, in my opinion, means your code is

- more compact
- easier to understand
- more robust
- easier to maintain
- more flexible

Answer (score 0):

I think you should use `fct_recode()`:

```r
library(tidyverse)
var <- factor(rep(letters[1:3], each = 5))
fct_recode(var, "new1" = "a", "new2" = "b", "new2" = "c")

#> [1] new1 new1 new1 new1 new1 new2 new2 new2 new2 new2 new2 new2 new2 new2 new2
#> Levels: new1 new2
```

for more example, check [r4ds book](https://r4ds.had.co.nz/factors.html#modifying-factor-levels).

Comment: Hi, I have tried this. Again, this is working if I run it individually but when executed using a for loop it is throwing the following error.
>Error: `f` must be a factor (or character vector).

Answer (score 0):

You use the function factor as follows:

```
data[,i] = factor(data[,i], 
                  levels= c("Do not Agree (1)",
                            "Somewhat Agree (2)",
                            "Completely Agree (3)"
                  ))
```

You can also check the different re-leveling functions in `tidyverse`. For example the `fct_relevel` function.
https://forcats.tidyverse.org/reference/fct_relevel.html

Comment: I am not trying to relevel the factors here. Rather, I am trying to recode them. 

I want to merge the levels Somewhat Agree and Do not Agree and code them as 0 and Completely Agree to 1.